# Laravel Collection CONCACT extremely slow when a large data set

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections

```
//around 10k records
$note       = NotesRecord::select('*')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->get();

//around 3k records    
$others     = Other::select('*')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->get();

//Create empty collection and merge the data
$allItems = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
$allItems = $allItems->concat($note);
$allItems = $allItems->concat($others);

return $allItems;
```

**Question:** Above code is to select the data from 2 tables from database, after select I will merge this 2 data set into it. But I currently facing one issue which is slow return when have the huge data set. If the table below 2k data it will only took less than 2 seconds to return but once have more than 10k it will took almost 18s to return the data. Does any expert have facing this issue before? Might share your experience and how to enhance it?

Comment: Indexing data and using Redis or other DB cache solutions may help you execute queries faster.

Comment: Since you are concatenating them do you need to order them?

Comment: Retrieving that much data in both tables is not recommended? Why are you retrieving that much data? Is is possible to run an aggregated query to achieve what you want?